# Convert for loop into a recursive function

Tags: java

this is a homework problem. I'm having trouble converting the following into a recursive function:

```
public class Integrate {
    public static double integrate(int  a, int b, int steps)
    {
        double sum=0;
        double delta = 1.0 * (b - a)/steps;
        double x = a;
        double f = 0.5*x*x + 3*x + 5;

        for (int i = 0; i< steps; i++)
        {
            x = x + delta;
            double fr = 0.5*x*x + 3*x + 5;
            double area = f * delta + 0.5*(fr - f)*delta;
            sum += area;
            f = fr;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int a, b, step;
        a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        step = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.format("Integral is %f\n", integrate(a,b,step));
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far but the output is not the same as the original code. I can't figure out what is wrong

```
public class Integrate {

    public static double integrate(int a, int b, int steps) {
        double sum=0;
        int i=0;
        sum = rintegrate(a, b, steps, i, sum);
        return sum;
    }

    public static double rintegrate(int a, int b, int steps, 
            int i, double sum) {
        double delta = 1.0 * (b - a)/steps;
        double x = a;
        double f = 0.5*x*x + 3*x + 5;
        if (i<steps) {
            x = x + delta;
            double fr = 0.5*x*x + 3*x + 5;
            double area = f * delta + 0.5*(fr - f)*delta;
            sum += area;
            f = fr;
            i++;
            rintegrate(a, b, steps, i, sum);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, step;
        a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        step = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.format("Integral is %f\n", integrate(a,b,step));
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the output from your original code? and what is the output from your new code?

Comment: Looks like you're not using the return value from your `rintegrate` recursively...

Comment: a = 1, b = 10, step=1000....... the original comes out to 360.000061 and mine outputs 0.076662

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza, I don't understand. How do I use the return value recursively?

Comment: I think he means you're not using it from within **rintegrate()**. That's probably your problem right there.

Comment: The elephant in the room, however, is why do it recursively at all? Is this a learning exercise? Iteration is almost always more efficient than recursion.

Comment: Oh, one more thing I want to point out: if *steps* is large and the stack is small, you're going to throw an exception.

Comment: @user2378481 Don't remove the code from the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to fully analyze the problem, but here are some observations that I have

```
    if (i<steps) {
        x = x + delta;
        double fr = 0.5*x*x + 3*x + 5;
        double area = f * delta + 0.5*(fr - f)*delta;
        sum += area;
        f = fr;
        i++;
        rintegrate(a, b, steps, i, sum);
    }
    return sum;
```

everything between `sum += area;` and `return sum;` is superfluous.

- you're setting `f` to `fr`, but you never even use `f` after that.  if you want `f` to be different next time, maybe you can pass it as a parameter to your recursive function
- you're recursively calling `rintegrate(...)`, but you're not doing anything with the value it returns.  you might want to use that value.

---

You should think about recursion as using a smaller version of a problem to solve itself.

Here's some code for your problem assuming that you have a function: `segment` that just calculates the size of the first segment given `a`, and `delta`

```
rintegrate(a, b, steps)
{
    if(steps <= 1)
    {
        delta = b-a;
        return segment(a, delta)
    }
    else
    {
        delta = (b-a)/steps
        return segment(a, delta) + rintegrate(a+delta, b, steps-1)
    }
}
```

Comment: With your example, is it calculating from steps and then going down? Is there a way to do it starting from 0?

Comment: @user2378481 you're still thinking about the problem iteratively.  Try thinking about the problem recursively.  Your function needs to add one segment, to the sum of the rest of the segments, and return that value

Comment: It's still kind of hard to understand. Is it like carrying over everything from previous step? Sorry, recursion just looks like a loop to me.

Comment: @user2378481 think of it this way.  Suppose i called your iterative `integrate` function from the example instead of calling the recursive `reintegrate` function.  Would the example make sense that way?

Comment: No, it won't. Is there a reason for recursion? It seems like it is more complicated and the output is less apparent when you rewrite this problem recursively.

Comment: @user2378481  forget whether it makes sense.  would it work when you do that though?

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant that it does make sense!

Comment: @user2378481  Whenever you recursively call your function, Don't think of it as your own incomplete function.  Think of it as though it were some magical function, that just finds the correct answer for whatever smaller version of your problem that you want

Comment: @user2378481 All you have to do is make sure that your function works for `f(x)` whenever it works `f(x-1)`.  and then you have to cover the base case of `f(1)`

Answer (score 1):

**Working version**

Just copy paste and you will get the same output as your original method.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1, b = 10, step = 1000;
            double delta = 1.0 * (b - a) / step;
        double sum = integrate(a, b, step, 0, 0, 0, delta);
        double test = working(a, b, step);
        System.out.println("Integral is " + sum);
        System.out.println("Integral is " + test);
    }
```

**The working recursive version:**

```
    public static double integrate(double x, int b, int steps, int i,
            double sum, double f, double delta) { 
        f = 0.5 * x * x + 3 * x + 5;
        if (i < steps) {
            x = x + delta;
            double fr = 0.5 * x * x + 3 * x + 5;
            double area = f * delta + 0.5 * (fr - f) * delta;
            return integrate(x, b, steps, i + 1, sum + area, fr, delta);
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

**Your original iterative method;**

```
public static double working(int a, int b, int steps) {
    double sum = 0;
    double delta = 1.0 * (b - a) / steps;
    double x = a;
    double f = 0.5 * x * x + 3 * x + 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        x = x + delta;
        double fr = 0.5 * x * x + 3 * x + 5;
        double area = f * delta + 0.5 * (fr - f) * delta;
        sum += area;
        f = fr;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. Your code is not giving the right output either. The hw problems said to call rintegrate from integrate which was why I had the rintegrate method in the first place.

Comment: I see. Yours works now. It's kinda not what I'm looking for but it's helpful to see what's wrong with mine. I don't get where do you calculate delta in your version?

Comment: Thanks, I've got a working solution now by declaring delta and x outside the recursive method. But why would they vary between calls if none of the variables associated with them are altered?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want ;)

```
public class Integrate{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, step;
        a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        step = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        System.out.format("Integral is %f\n",
                adaptiveSimpsons(a, b, step));

    }

    private static double f(double i) {
        return (0.5 * i * i + 3 * i + 5);
    }

    static double adaptiveSimpsons(double a, double b, // interval [a,b]
            int maxRecursionDepth) { // recursion cap
        double c = (a + b) / 2, h = b - a;
        double fa = f(a), fb = f(b), fc = f(c);
        double S = (h / 6) * (fa + 4 * fc + fb);
        return adaptiveSimpsonsAux(a, b, S, fa, fb, fc, maxRecursionDepth);
    }

    private static double adaptiveSimpsonsAux(double a, double b, double S, double fa,
            double fb, double fc, int bottom) {
        double c = (a + b) / 2, h = b - a;
        double d = (a + c) / 2, e = (c + b) / 2;
        double fd = f(d), fe = f(e);
        double Sleft = (h / 12) * (fa + 4 * fd + fc);
        double Sright = (h / 12) * (fc + 4 * fe + fb);
        double S2 = Sleft + Sright;
        if (bottom <= 0)
            return S2 + (S2 - S) / 15;
        return adaptiveSimpsonsAux(a, c, Sleft, fa, fc, fd, bottom - 1)
                + adaptiveSimpsonsAux(c, b, Sright, fc, fb, fe, bottom - 1);
    }
}
```

Tested and Working

Translated C code given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Simpson%27s_method)

Comment: No, the integration you are trying to do recursively can be done recursively using simpsons algorithm and as such the methods are named that way.  Did you even look at the code? It recursively integrates the function 0.5x^2 + 3x + 5 up to a given number of steps, as stated in OP.  If you copy my code into eclipse and run it, you will see that it calculates, recursively, the integral wanted...